# Swapping the order of operators in the operator product expansion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory

I'm looking at the $\beta-\gamma$  ghost CFT, although my question holds more generally for any OPE in any conformal field theory.

The OPE of the two  defining fields is $$\beta(z) \gamma(w) \sim \frac{1}{z-w}.$$

To do calculations I also need to know the OPE $$\gamma(z) \beta(w)\sim \;?\;.$$
How can I calculate this using the first OPE?  I know this OPE needs to be $\pm$ the first one (and I also know that won't hold more generally for any OPE).

Is the point that I can swap the operators around however I like because they're radially ordered, and so $\beta(z) \gamma(w) = \gamma(w)\beta(z)$?

I tried to repurpose [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56190/commutation-of-operator-product-expansion)  to my current question, but I've always found the OPE a bit cryptic and I need it spelt out to me in simple baby steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a spell-out in toddler steps. From the $\beta\gamma$ path integral you can derive that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\bar{\partial}\beta(z)\,\gamma(w)&=&-2\pi \delta(z-w)\delta(\bar{z}-\bar{w}) \\ 
\bar{\partial}\gamma(z)\,\beta(w)&=&2\pi \delta(z-w)\delta(\bar{z}-\bar{w}).
\end{array}
$$
Together with the normal ordering $:\ :$, the fact that the $\beta\gamma$ system is a free theory, and the identity
$$ \bar{\partial}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = 2\pi\delta(z)\delta(\bar{z})$$
you get
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
:\beta(z)\,\gamma(w):&=& \beta(z)\,\gamma(w) + \dfrac{1}{z-w} \\
:\gamma(z)\,\beta(w):&=& \gamma(z)\,\beta(w) - \dfrac{1}{z-w}, \\
\end{array}
$$
which in turn implies that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\beta(z)\,\gamma(w) &\sim& -\dfrac{1}{z-w} \\
\gamma(z)\,\beta(w) &\sim&  \dfrac{1}{z-w}. \\
\end{array}
$$
Note that this gives $\beta(z)\gamma(w)=\gamma(w)\beta(z)=-\gamma(z)\beta(w)$.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can swap them around as long as they are Bosonic fields. Fermions get a minus sign.